# OnClickListener of ImageButton android

Tags: android

**I have implement one application in which four image button and on image button has four animal picture like this :**

```
 deer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
           .. . .. . . .
    });
 Fox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
           .. . .. . . .
    });
 lion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
           .. . .. . . .
    });
 monkey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
           .. . .. . . .
    });
```

Now problem is when i am click on lion , other 3 clickListner are not disable.so when user click on lion at that time click on deer flag will true both. or some time flag will true all.

in simple language i want disable remain clickListner if i am click on any one.

so can you help me.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
    Fox.setClickable(false);
    Lion.setClickable(false);
    Monkey.setClickable(false);

           .. . .. . . .
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Each image button has different listeners , so it should not call other listeners other than the buttons you are touching. May be you have to reset the flags depending on your implementation.